# Front end ajax user login session issue

Tags: front-end, session

I am having an issue where the ajax login form allows me to login, sort of. If I set the redirect to the homepage after login it sends me to the homepage and gives me the admin bar at the top. However if I try to then go to the admin dashboard it asks me to login again with the normal wordpress login.

How can solve this issue? My codes:

in page-login.php template:

```
<form id="login" class="ajax-auth" action="login" method="post">
    <p class="status"></p>  
    <?php wp_nonce_field('ajax-login-nonce', 'security'); ?>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="username" placeholder="<?php _e('Username','my-theme'); ?>" type="text" class="required form-control" name="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="password" placeholder="<?php _e('Password','my-theme'); ?>" type="password" class="required form-control" name="password">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-info" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Login','my-theme'); ?>">
</form>
```

in functions.php:

```
function ajax_auth_init(){  
  global $theme_options;
  $userProfilePage=$theme_options['opt-user-select'];

  wp_register_script('ajax-auth-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-logreg-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
  wp_enqueue_script('ajax-auth-script');

  wp_localize_script( 'ajax-auth-script', 'ajax_auth_object', array( 
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => get_page_link($userProfilePage),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Please wait...','my-theme')
  ));

  // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}
// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_auth_init');
}
function ajax_login(){

  // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
  check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    // Call auth_user_login
  auth_user_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], __('Login','my-theme')); 

  die();
}
function auth_user_login($user_login, $password, $login){
  $info = array();
  $info['user_login'] = $user_login;
  $info['user_password'] = $password;
  $info['remember'] = true;

  $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong password or username.','my-theme')));
    } else {
    wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID); 
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=> $login.__(' successful, redirecting...','my-theme')));
    }

  die();
}
```

and ajax-logreg-script.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Perform AJAX login/register on form submit
    $('form#login, form#register').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!$(this).valid()) return false;
        $('p.status', this).show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage);
        action = 'ajaxlogin';
        username =  $('form#login #username').val();
        password = $('form#login #password').val();
        email = '';
        security = $('form#login #security').val(); 
        ctrl = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': action,
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
                'email': email,
                'security': security,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('p.status', ctrl).text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true)
                  document.location.href = ajax_auth_object.redirecturl;
                else if (ctrl == 'register')
                  grecaptcha.reset();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".logreg-page form#login").validate({
        ignore: ".ignore",
       rules: {
         username: {
            required: true,
          },
          password: {
            required: true,
          },
       },
       messages: {
          username: "Please enter an username.",
          password: "Please enter your password.",
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting an authentication cookie. The second parameter of the [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function is set to false.

> This function sets an authentication cookie. Users will not be logged in if it is not sent.

```
$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, true );
```

That should give you the result you desire

Comment: You're wrong. The user is logged in in both cases, but is logged out when he wants to go to the admin panel. The second parameter in wp_signon is used for secure cookie. In the new version of Wordpress, it is enough to leave it blank. I also solved the problem by leaving it blank. But I'm having a new problem. The page refreshes when the user logs in, but the login form continues to appear. When the F5 button is pressed manually, it appears to be logged in. This is because of the browser cache. I need to find a way to clear the browser cache when the user logs in. Is there a way to trigger thi